# How to setup Strongswan to auth to LDAP?

Tags: vpn, ldap, ipsec, l2tp

I'm trying to create an L2TP/IPSEC VPN server in 20.04 that uses LDAP for user authentication.

I'm assuming Strongswan does this.

Where, in Strongswan or other configs would I add the LDAP server info?

Or does it just use SSSD or PAM or something else and you just point Strongswan to that?

I'm specifically looking for LDAP, not Radius. I know radius is possible.

*Any help would be appreciated. I realize there are a few questions close to this one. But all their answers require a GUI. This a cloud server, so no gui. Thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that ExploitFate provided is correct.

Also, in libreswan, you simply need this in ipsec.conf after you know PAM is working:

xauthby=pam

and comment out "xauthby=file"

Answer (score 0):

[strongSwan does not natively support LDAP authentication](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/2320) but it looks like you can somehow use FreeRADIUS as a go-between.

Comment: https://lists.strongswan.org/pipermail/users/2018-January/012166.html